# Why does inflating a view in getView() cause an exception?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to inflate a new view in the getView() method in one of my app's fragments. To do this, I create an LayoutInflater, and then inflate convertView:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_my_search, parent);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

However, when I do this, I get this exception:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #101: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

What is causing this problem?

Comment: convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_my_search, parent); it is causing, just do  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_my_search, null);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_my_search, parent, false);`

The 2 param method is trying to attach the view to the parent, throwing the Exception

Answer (score 0):

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_my_search, parent); // here
 your trying to add the view in parent make sure you remove all views and then  add.
```

instead of that use simple techniques like

```
1. convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_my_search, parent, false);//
here your inflating view but not adding the parent.(false flag)


2 convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_my_search, null)//
here your not supplying any parent.
```